# error occurred submitting an edit

Tags: bug, editing

I keep getting this error whenever I tried to make an edit or post a question/answer:

[image: error]

Yet, my edit goes through. I am not sure why this happens to me and what I can do to fix this. Any recommendations? Google wasn't giving me any exact reason.

Comment: Have you checked the status pages on the SE network? Also your dev tools console for errors? Maybe you have been receiving time outs? From a quick check on your profile: You are fine and "a model citizen" and not blocked by a ban.

Comment: I get this kind of errors because my wifi is not very stable.

Comment: @kaiser The reason for my error was my unstable WiFi. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This message is generated by a client side script called `post-validation` that is called after you have submitted something to the server. The script sets a time-out for hearing back from the server that the submission has been received.

When you are on a slow (or irregular) connection, the script will always time out and you will receive this warning. It doesn't necessarily mean, as you have found, that something actually went wrong.

Comment: Yes, this was the issue, thank you.